# Can't pass C# int array to VBA Excel macro

Tags: c#, vba, excel, macros

I'm trying to call a macro of my Excel worksheet (2003) from my C# application with the C# Interop.

It worked fine before with Integer parameters. But now I need to pass an Array of Integers and I keep getting a type mismatch exception.

```
COMException: Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
```

The C# code looks like this:

```
object m = Type.Missing;    
xlApp.Run("MergeColumnsKeepValues", lastGroupRowExcel, firstGroupRowExcel, mergeColumns, rightFormatMergeColumn,
                        multiRowColumn, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m);
```

where all the parameters are of type `Int32`, except `mergeColumns` which is an `Int32[9]`

The VBA macro inside my Excel template looks like this:

```
Sub MergeColumnsKeepValues(lastGroupRow As Integer, firstGroupRow As Integer, mergeColumns() As Variant, helpColumnMerge As Integer, multiRowColumn As Integer)
    ... <- no use of array, just declaring variables and stuff
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(mergeColums) To UBound(mergeColumns)
        Set targetMergeCells = Range(Cells(firstGroupRow, mergeColumns(i)), Cells(lastGroupRow, mergeColumns(i)))
        Call targetMergeCells.PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormats, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False)
    Next
End Sub
```

I tried declaring the Array `ByRef` in VBA and I tried declaring it as `Variant` array but nothing changed. I tried to place a MsgBox at the start to see if the mismatch occurs in the loop or at the parameter level and it doesn't show the MsgBox.
Does anyone know how to fix this or what the cause is?

Comment: lastGroupRowExcel, firstGroupRowExcel, mergeColumns, rightFormatMergeColumn,
                        multiRowColumn,

Comment: which one is the array?

Comment: Regarding that question, I would like to refer to the sentence below the C#  code: "where all the parameters are of type Int32, except mergeColumns which is an Int32[9]"

Comment: ah sorry, didn't notice

Comment: did you try `mergeColumns() As Integer` at first? or what?

Comment: Yes, I tried: `mergeColumns() As Integer`, `mergeColumns() As Variant` and `ByRef mergeColumns() As Integer`, all without change to the C# code and all with the same error.

Comment: what is innerException

Comment: Well, it's null of course. I've never seen an Excel COM Exception with an inner exception.

Comment: I saw somewhere that they were referencing type.missing to caller, like `ref m`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115512/discussion-between-manuel-hoffmann-and-jackjop).

Comment: Please post your answer then :) ... I'm playing around with it myself and would like to know what I'm missing.

Comment: Does this offer any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531011/how-to-pass-an-array-from-c-sharp-vsto-project-to-vba-macro

Comment: @Nathan_Sav If you mean the Long() array, I'll try that and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XL.Application xlapp = new XL.Application();
            xlapp.Visible = true;
            xlapp.Workbooks.Open("c:/test/test_c.xlsm");
            int[] x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            xlapp.Run("MergeColumnsKeepValues", x, 2, 3, 4,5);

        }
```

calling VBA as follows

```
Public Sub MergeColumnsKeepValues(ByRef lastGroupRow As Variant, _
                                    firstGroupRow As Integer, _
                                    mergeColumns As Integer, _
                                    helpColumnMerge As Integer, _
                                    multiRowColumn As Integer)
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: So, how do I get the integer array from the variant?

Comment: `For i = 0 To UBound(lastGroupRow)
        Debug.Print i
    Next I`

Comment: I tried passing the array as a `Long` array while leaving it as `int[]` in C# and it worked. So I'll be using the `Long` array solution, but I'm pretty sure this solution would work as well. Since you were also the one to direct me to the `Long` array solution, I'm going to accept this answer while leaving the hint that it works with passing the array as `Long ()`