# Pass array to macro function from C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba

I am trying to pass an array variable as a parameter to a macro function but getting the error mismatch on calling this macro file,

My code is as follows, MACRO CODE

```vb
Sub arraydef(arr() As Variant)
    MsgBox (arr(0))
End Sub
```

C# Code for calling the Macro function by passing the array :

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath("\\MacroFile\\MYTEFINAL1.xlsm"));
xlApp.Visible = false;
xlApp.Run("arraydef", Countryarr);
```

Where Countryarr is the array that i am trying to pass

Can someone please suggest on how to pass an array to a macro file as my functionality depends on it?

Comment: {"Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"} getting this error while calling macro

Comment: does `Run` take a string as 1st argument? - just checking...

Comment: yes, here xlApp is excel object and this codes runs fine with other datatypes except for array

Comment: but the macro defined the arr as `variant` - that could be a problem...

Comment: show code def of `CountryArr`

Comment: Here for Country Array I am obtaining data from front end code is as follows,

Comment: int SelectedCountryCount = liCountry.Items.Count;

            string[] Countryarr = new string[SelectedCountryCount];

            for (i = 0; i < SelectedCountryCount; i++)
            {
                Countryarr[i] = liCountry.Items[i].ToString();
            }

Comment: try declaring the array to pass as type `object`

Comment: Please, don't put code in a comment. Move it to the question.

Comment: Have you tried to define the VBA-routine with `Sub arraydef(arr As Variant)`

Comment: Hi declaring Sub arraydef(arr As Variant) instead of Sub arraydef(arr() as Variant) works, here () seems to be the problem. Syntax issue.Thanks FunThomas i have been having this issue for a long time

Comment: @FunThomas As this is something of an FAQ (and I don't find an exact duplicate, only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010974/cant-pass-c-sharp-int-array-to-vba-excel-macro) might be a good idea to write this up as an Answer. Ping me an I'll help by up-voting and I hope the OP marks it as "the" answer so that we have a good post to point people at...

Comment: @ Cindy Meister: Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when passing an array of *something* to a subroutine in VBA, the easiest solution is to declare the parameter as `Variant`.

Declaring the parameter as array means that the calling routine must pass exactly that array type. If a subroutine is declared to receive an array of `Long`, you have to pass an array of `Long`. Not `Integer`, not `Variant`. The same is true if the subroutine is declared to receive an array of `Variant` - you have to pass an array of `Variant`.

Now, `Variant` is a kind of magical data type. A variant can be *anything* - even an array. When you declare a parameter as `Variant` and pass a `Long` (or a `String`, or...), the VBA Runtime Engine takes care about that a `Variant` is created, stores the content of the `Long` (or `String` or...) and keeps track about what it currently stores.

If you pass an array to that Variant, VBA stores that array in the `Variant` (probably only a reference) and keeps track not only about the fact that it contains an array but also about the type of the array.

However, if you declare the parameter as an array of `Variant`, the Runtime cannot do its magic. You tell the Runtime you will get a bunch of `Variants`, but then you pass a bunch of `Integer`. The Runtime would have to convert every single element of the array from `Integer` to `Variant` - and it simply does not do that. Instead, the VBA compiler complains, or, when calling via `Application.Run`, throws a *"Type mismatch"* runtime error.

There are some functions that can help you get information what is (currently) stored in a Variant: `IsArray` tells you if the `Variant` contains an error, and `VarType` will give you the information about the type (for more information about `VarType`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function). `LBound` and `Ubound` will give you the size of an array. The only thing you cannot get is the information about the dimensions of an array. In the rare case you don't know about the number of dimensions, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6902088/7599798 can give you a solution.